# Switch fragments through spinner in toolbar

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, android-spinner

This is driving me crazy. I'm trying to switch `fragments` by using a `spinner`, but I can't figure out where my mistake is. When I click on one of the `spinner` items, it always shows me the content of ***fragment 3***, the others will not appear.

I browsed through the internet for hours now, but couldn't find a understandable solution for my problem, since I'm new to android programming.

Thankful for any help!

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Setup spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(
                toolbar.getContext(),
                new String[]{
                        "Fragment 1",
                        "Fragment 2",
                        "Fragment 3"
                }));

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
                // container view.
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, Fragment1.newInstance()).commit();
                    case 1:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, Fragment2.newInstance()).commit();
                    default:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.container, Fragment3.newInstance()).commit();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1Fragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment1Fragment newInstance() {
        Fragment1Fragment fragment = new Fragment1Fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Fragment1Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dear,

```
    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, Fragment1.newInstance()).commit();

                            break;
                        case 1:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, Fragment2.newInstance()).commit();
                            break;
                        default:
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.container, Fragment3.newInstance()).commit();
                           break;
                    }
```

Without **break** statement your all 3 lines executed. So the 3rd Fragment.

Comment: I want to Display Different RecyclerViews in the different Fragments, is this the right approach for that?

Comment: You are just doing transaction here...what each fragment does, its Fragment's own business.